# Textfields shrinking whenever keyboard appears in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create an simple login form, there are 3 components in a column: row and 2 text fields.

The row contains an image and text.

The problem is whenever the keyboard appears while I want to type something in the textfield, all UI is shrinking.

I have attached before and after keyboard appears[image: before_keyboard]

[image: after_keyboard]

How to make it such that whenever keyboard appears the elements hidden below the keyboard?

Here is my code:

```
Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Flexible(
            fit: FlexFit.tight,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Flexible(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
                    child: Hero(
                      tag: "logo",
                        child: Image.asset(
                          "images/flash.png", width: 70, height: 50,)
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Flexible(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
                    child: Text(
                      "Demo Chat",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 40,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Flexible(
            fit: FlexFit.tight,
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 50,
            ),
          ),
          Flexible(
            fit: FlexFit.tight,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: TextField(
                decoration: kTextFieldDecorationEmail,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Flexible(
            fit: FlexFit.tight,
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 50,
            ),
          ),
          Flexible(
            fit: FlexFit.tight,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: TextField(
                decoration: kTextFieldDecorationPassword,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
                obscureText: true,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Flexible(
            fit: FlexFit.tight,
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 70,
            ),
          ),
          Flexible(
            fit: FlexFit.tight,
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: MaterialButton(
                color: Colors.blueAccent,
                onPressed: (){},
                height: 50,
                child: Text(
                  "Login",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black
                  ),
                ),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: Add your code so that others can help you better https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are using flexible with FlexFit.tight, this allows it to fit into screen regardless of the size. I would suggest you to use MediaQuery or some other field for this to tackle. An example to eliminate this would be something like this. I have edited your code a slight bit since I do not have the image and decoration at the moment which you are using I have put in some random one for the time being.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
                  child: Text(
                    "Demo Chat",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 40,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 50,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  hintText: 'Username',
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: Colors.grey,
                  contentPadding:
                      const EdgeInsets.only(left: 14.0, bottom: 6.0, top: 8.0),
                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  ),
                  enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  ),
                ),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 50,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  hintText: 'Password',
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: Colors.grey,
                  contentPadding:
                      const EdgeInsets.only(left: 14.0, bottom: 6.0, top: 8.0),
                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  ),
                  enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  ),
                ),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
                obscureText: true,
              ),
            ),
            Flexible(
              fit: FlexFit.tight,
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 70,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: MaterialButton(
                color: Colors.blueAccent,
                onPressed: () {},
                height: 50,
                child: Text(
                  "Login",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                ),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Screen:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I got it to work, what I did was I wrapped all sized box with flexible, so even on smaller screen sizes only sized box will shrink but not textfields and buttons

Comment: @Aditya Glad you did it :)